# Solving general linear ODE $\sum_{k=0}^n y^{(k)}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Is there a way to solve this general linear ODE:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n y^{(k)}=0$$

For the first few $n$ here are the solutions:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
n & y \\
\hline 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & c_1 e^x \\ 
2 & c_1 e^{x/2} \sin \left( \frac{\sqrt 3}2 x\right)+c_2 e^{x/2} \cos \left( \frac{\sqrt 3}2 x\right)\\ 
3 & c_1e^{-x}+c_2 \sin x + c_3 \cos x\\ 
4 &  c_1 e^{- \left(1+\sqrt5\right) x/4} \sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt5}8} x\right)+c_2e^{- \left(1-\sqrt5\right) x/4} \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt5}8} x\right)+c_3 e^{- \left(1-\sqrt5\right) x/4} \sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt5}8} x\right)+c_4 e^{- \left(1+\sqrt5\right) x/4} \cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt5}8} x\right) \\
\vdots & \vdots
\end{array}$$

---

My attempt:

We have $$\mathscr{L}\left\{\sum_{k=0}^ny^{(k)}\right\}=0\\
\sum_{k=0}^n \left( s^k \bar y-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} s^i c_{i+1}\right)=0\\
\bar y = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}c_{i+1} s^i}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^ns^k}\\
y = \mathscr L^{-1}\left\{\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}c_{i+1} s^i}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^ns^k}\right\}$$
<s>I do not know how to evaluate that Laplace expression.</s>
Changing the summation index of the top sum and realising that the bottom is a geometric series we get that $$y=\mathscr L ^{-1}\left \{ \sum^n_{k=1}(n+1-k)\frac{(1-s)s^{k-1}}{1-s^{n+1}}\right \}$$
So I am just left with the evaluation of $$\mathscr L ^{-1}\left \{ \frac{(1-s)s^{k-1}}{1-s^{n+1}}\right \}$$
Mathematica cannot seems to evaluate this Laplace expression. Let $*$ define the convolution operator such that: $\mathscr L \left \{ f*g\right \}=\bar f \bar g$.

Therefore $$\mathscr L ^{-1}\left \{ \frac{(1-s)s^{k-1}}{1-s^{n+1}}\right \}=\left[x^{-k} \left ( \frac1{\Gamma(1-k)}-\frac1{x\Gamma(-k)}\right )\right]*\mathscr L^{-1}\left\{\frac1{1-s^{n+1}}\right\}$$
Now I am really stuck.

Comment: How much have you learned about complex roots of unity?

Comment: @ErickWong I know about complex roots of unity and some complex analysis.

Comment: Great, then you should be able to recognize that marty's answer is the key to understanding the common pattern to the coefficients in your table above (hint: $e^{(a+bi)x} = e^{ax} (\cos bx + i \sin bx)$).  If it's important to you that the basis representatives are real-valued functions, then think about how the roots pair into complex conjugates (this will work out slightly differently depending on whether $n$ is odd or even).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $y(x) = e^{ax}$,
$y^{(k)}(x)
=a^k e^{ax}
$,
so
$\sum_{k=0}^n a^k
= 0$
so,
multiplying by $a-1$,
$a^{n+1}-1
= 0
$.

Therefore,
$e^{ax}$
is a particular solution
for all $a$
such that
$a^{n+1} = 1$
with $a \ne 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer I understand it now.